# Showing err at '@angular/http' while importing

Tags: angular

I was facing some issue with `@angular/http` while importing in `app.module.ts`.

Tried with below code

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

But unable to access get method like below

`'this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")`

But in some tutorials, i see the code like below

`import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`

On trying, i'm getting error like 'Cannot find module '@angular/http'

```
this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
      map((response) ⇒ response.json()).
      subscribe((data) ⇒ console.log(data))
```

I expect something like above..

Comment: `@angular/common/http`

Comment: this is a bit silly question in my opinion. Should perhaps look at the documentation, as compiler clearly tells you that you are trying to import from wrong place ;)

Comment: This got resolved.. I need to use    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; in app.module.ts and import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; in components/service.. This is a recent change made by angular it seems.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> `@angular/http` has been removed starting with version 8.0.0 (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#removed-apis)).

Use `@angular/common/http` instead.

To update your apps:

- Replace HttpModule with HttpClientModule (from @angular/common/http) in each of your modules.
- Replace the Http service with the HttpClient service.
- Remove any map(res => res.json()) calls. They are no longer needed.

For more information about using @angular/common/http, see the [HttpClient guide](https://angular.io/guide/http). (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp))